# Task queue java

Tags: java, api, queue, task

Hi i'm new to Task queue java API i tried a simple Example for it. My idea is to redirect the queue file to a servlet and to print some statement in the servlet.But it doesn't work. i mapped web.xml and used default queue I didnt get any Error but the file is not redirected to servlet . this is the codee i followed

```
taskq.java
           public class taskq extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throwsIOException {


    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();

    System.out.println("taskqueue");
    queue.add(url("/worker"));

}
    worker.java
         public class worker extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String s;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws IOException {
    String s="crimsom";
    System.out.println(s);
}

 }
```

Please Help me on this issue.
Regards
Sharun.

Answer (score 2):

You should add your output to the servlet response, instead of `System.out`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>Hello world</title></head>");
    out.println("<body><h1>taskqueue</h1></body></html>");

    queue.add(url("/worker"));
}
```

Comment: The code i followed is right? Just for checking i used system.out.

Comment: thanks a lot. If u have complete & simple Task queue program Please Post it. It will be very useful for beginners like me.And it will be easier to understand the concept.

Comment: I don't know the task queue API, this is basic servlet stuff so far. You will need to experiment / google yourself...

Comment: ya thank you. I used your code as it in my example It display the title and body text but the process in the worker servlet is not called... do you know what problem it is please help me